# Ayuda en resolver algoritmo mostrar cifras que se repiten - Java

Tags: java

Estimada comunidad, quisiera apoyo en resolver este algoritmo:

Ingrese un número natural cualquiera, para mostrar las cifras que se repiten y la cantidad de veces que estas se repiten.
Ejemplo:

```
Ingrese un número natural cualquiera: 471757347
El numero 4: se repite  2 Veces
El numero 7: se repite  4 Veces
```

He podido sacar el número mayor o menor pero solo los dos, en caso de tres o cuatro números repetidos no llego a resolverlos. Espero su orientación para resolver este problema. Gracias.

Este es el código que tengo hasta el momento:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner linea = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n, digito, digito1, repetir;
    System.out.print("Introduce un número entero: ");
    n = linea.nextInt();
    repetir = 0;
    digito1 = 0;
    do {
        digito = n % 10;
        if (digito > digito1) {

            digito1 = digito;
            repetir = 1;
        } else {

            if (digito == digito1) {
                repetir++;
            }
        }
        n = n / 10;

    } while (n != 0);

    System.out.println("El numero " + digito1 + " se repite " + repetir + " veces");
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Por favor anexa el código que tienes.

Comment: Ya edite el mensaje, gracias por responder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si entiendo bien tu pregunta, lo que deseas es ver cuántas veces se repite cada dígito en un número natural cualquiera.

Se me ocurre esta solución (no la más eficiente, pero funciona):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner linea = new Scanner(System.in);
        long n;
        System.out.print("Introduce un número:\t");
        n = linea.nextLong();
        String num = String.valueOf(n);
        for(int d = 0; d < 10; d++) {
            int rep = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++) {
                if(Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(num.charAt(i))) == d) {
                    rep++;
                }
            }
            if(rep > 0) {
                System.out.println(
                    String.format("El número %d se repite %d %s", 
                                  d, rep, (rep == 1 ? "vez" : "veces"))
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo, solo falta pulir un poco la salida, pero se entiende, gracias.

Answer (score 2):

No entiendo qué quieres hacer con el if:

```
   if (digito > digito1) {
```

Eso serviría para buscar el dígito mayor, pero eso no tiene relevancia aquí.
Parece que hubieras copiado código de algún problema distinto...

En todo caso, debes almacenar en algún lado las veces que se repite cada dígito. Una manera cómoda en este caso es un array. Por ejemplo:

```
 public static void imprimirRepetidos(long number) {
     int[] cont = new int[10]; // cuenta la cantidad de apariciones de cada digito
     int digito;
     while(number >0) {
         digito = (int) (number % 10);
         cont[digito]++;
         number /= 10;
     }
     for(digito=0;digito<10;digito++) {
         if(cont[digito]>1)
            System.out.println("El digito " + digito + " se repite " + cont[digito]+ " veces");
     }
}
```

Asegúrate de entender cada parte del código.

Otra tema, de terminología: no mezcles "número", "cifra" y "dígito". Cada una de las cifras que se usan para representar un número en determinada base se llama "dígito" (puede ser decimal, hexadecimal, binario, etc - en este caso, se supone decimal).

Comment: Gracias pero el reto es hacerlo sin arreglos. puse el if porque estaba probando primero con los números mayores, pero me quede ahi, solo contaba los mayores, pero agradezco la respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Una alternativa es tratar el número como un string (obviamente validando antes que sea un número) y con `longitudNumero - longitudPrimerasOcurrencias` se obtendría la cantidad de veces que se repite. Te pongo un ejemplo:

```
Map<String, Integer> repeated = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        try(Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.print("Ingrese un número: ");
            // se asegura que sea un número
            Integer number = Integer.parseInt(kb.next());
            for(String n : String.valueOf(number).split("")) {
                // si el mapa no contiene el número procede
                if(!repeated.containsKey(n)) {
                    int numberLen = number.length();
                    int replacesLen = number.replace(n, "").length();
                    int ocurrences = (numberLen - replacesLen);
                    if(ocurrences > 1) {
                        repeated.put(n, ocurrences);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("No se ha ingresado un número");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : repeated.entrySet()) {
            System.out.printf("\nEl número %s se repite %d veces",
                                entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        System.out.println();
```

Salida:

```
Ingrese un número: 471757347

El número 4 se repite 2 veces
El número 7 se repite 4 veces
```

Comment: Funciona gracias, un poco tedioso el código pero se entiende, es un reto sin usar arreglos y objetos, pero me gusta tu código, gracias.

Comment: Es un poco tedioso porque uso un `try - catch` y un `Map` para guardar las ocurrencias, pero el código es sencillo en sí. Si tienes dudas acerca de ello, coméntalas y con gusto te explico.

Comment: El que dió voto negativo, que me diga el por qué por favor.

Comment: Hay bastantes haters en esta comunidad

Answer (score 0):

En este caso, un análisis del problema conduce a una solución sencilla:

Los digitos que se pueden repetir son 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Se necesita para cada digito una variable que lleve el conteo de sus repeticiones. Por ejemplo:

```
int numeroRepeticionesDigito0 = 0;
//...
int numeroRepeticionesDigito9 = 0;
```

Ahora, veo que ya tenes la forma de obtener cada digito por separado. Solo resta verificar dentro del ciclo que digito es el actual, e incrementar su variable en uno, lo cual se puede hacer con una estructura de control switch:

```
switch (digito)
{
    case 0: numeroRepeticionesDigito0++; break;
    case 9: numeroRepeticionesDigito9++; break;
}
```

Y después que termine el ciclo mostrar el valor de cada una de las variables que llevan el total de repeticiones. En este caso, como supongo que es una tarea, prefiero no mostrar el código completo, pero la idea es esa, sin utilizar instrucciones avanzadas, nada mas una estructura de repeticion (while) y una de control (switch). Para este tipo de problemas, te sugiero que analices el proceso mental de como lo resolverías tu, y luego tratar de traducir ese proceso mental en código.